# Poisson - Arrival of customers to a booth at exhibition

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose the number of customers visiting a booth at an exhibition is a Poisson with rate 14 customers per hour.

Find the probability that the first customer arrives at the box office within 5 minutes

This one should I use pmf or cdf ?

If I use pmf, then 
p(1) = 0.3633

Comment: The time between Poisson arrivals is exponentially distributed. Have you learned that?

Comment: What does $p(1)$ mean to you? That doesn't mean anything to me. Also, Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: p(1) mean pmf at k = 1

Comment: Yes, I know that Poisson can be approximate as Exponential Distribution if the mean is not below 5. 

These are all old exam question though, I have exam tmr. This is for practice

Comment: If you want to use the Poisson distribution, convert the parameter to suit the time period of  5 minutes, and then find the complement of the probability that no event occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N_t$ is the number of customer arriving in the interval $(0,t]$, then 
$$N_t\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda t= 14/\text{hr}\cdot t = 14/(60\text{ min})\cdot t).$$

Notice that the phrase "first customer arrives in the first five minutes" means
at least one customer in 5 mins. Hence, you are being asked for
$$P(N_5 \geq 1) \tag1$$

You can also recall that the time until the first arrival $T$ follows an exponential distribution with mean $1/\lambda$.
Hence, you are being asked
$$P(T\leq 5)\tag 2$$

Verify that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent. Hint: Try use the complementary probability instead.

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

Define a random variable $X$ to be the number of arrivals in the first $5$ minutes.  Then $X$ is Poisson with parameter $\frac{14}{12}$.  You are interested in the event $X\ge 1$, which is the complement of $X=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X=k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}; \qquad \lambda=\frac {14}{12}\quad\text{($5$ minute time-block)}\\
P(X\ge1)=1-P(X=0)=1-e^{-\frac{14}{12}}=0.6886$$